# select first div in table and toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

this should be simple - I want to use jquery to select the first div with the class="boxgrid captionfull" in the tr class="row-1 row-first" and toggle the class to 'active_labBeitrag'.

```
<table class="views-view-grid">
 <tbody>
   '<tr class="row-1 row-first">'
       '<td class="col-1">'
         '<span id="thmr_222" class="thmr_call">'
            '<div class="views-field-field-video-standbild-fid">
              '<span class="field-content"><span id="thmr_4" class="thmr_call">'
<div class="boxgrid captionfull" >..........
```

This doesn't work:
$('tr.row-1').children(".boxgrid").toggleClass('active_labBeitrag');

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.boxgrid` isn't an *immediate* child, do you need [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (which *only* looks at immediate children) here, like this:

```
$('tr.row-1').find('.boxgrid').toggleClass('active_labBeitrag');
```

Comment: Thanks - this gives me of course all '.boxgrid' in my first table row. Is it possible to get only the first '.boxgrid' div?

Comment: @jospBln - yup, just use  `.find('.boxgrid:first')` instead

Comment: @jospBln: please accept this answer if it has answered your query.